# Visual Studio Build Tools installer freezes during preparation

Tags: visual-studio, freeze

I am trying to install the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017, specifically version 15.9, on Windows 10. Such operating system is running inside a Virtual Machine launched by virtualbox on Ubuntu 22.04.

As I launch the executable, after asking for admin permissions, a small window pops up with a completion bar and a single text label. When the bar reaches 100% and the label says `Preparing: C:\Users\...\vs_startup_bootstrapper.json`, the whole Virtual Machine freezes, to the point that virtualbox is not responding anymore.

The only other known instance of this issue I have been able to find was reported on the [Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/ed7d8cd1-6740-4490-b05e-bcbeba4e737f/microsoft-visual-studio-installer-stuck?forum=vssetup)  and was attributed to an antivirus blocking the installer. This seems not to be the issue in my case, as

1. I do not have an antivirus running;
2. even if I disable Windows Defender, the freeze happens.

I have also tried increasing the RAM space allocated to the VM and leaving it be for a couple of hours, supposing that the installer was taking a long time unpacking the necessary files, but this also is no solution.

Furthermore, the exact same problem arises if I try and launch the newest version (2022) of the generic Visual Studio Installer.

How would I go about diagnosing where the issue is?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I side-stepped the issue by configuring a dual boot on my machine, instead of a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating more cores to the virtual machine resolved the issue for me.

On a single core VM the issue occurred, but on a 3-core machine it did not.

Comment: That I do not recall trying out. I will try it when I have the opportunity, thanks for sharing this solution